# How can I get information out of a junction table using JPA/EclipseLink?

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, eclipselink, entitymanager

I have the following many-to-many mapping:

`public class Student implements
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer xID;`

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "x_y", 
           joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "xID")},
           inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="yID")})
private Set<Cat> cats;
```

}

public class Cat implements
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer yID;

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "x_y", 
           joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "yID")},
           inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="xID")})
private Set<Student> students;
```

}

Please ignore the object and property names, they are ficticious and irrelevant. This compiles and works fine. I can also do this:

`Entitymanager em = emf.createEntityManager();`

em.getTransaction().begin();
Student s = new Student();
Student s2 = new Student();
Cat c = new Cat();
em.persist(s);
em.persist(s2);
em.persist(c);
s.getCats().add(c);
c.getStudents().add(s2);
em.getTransaction().commit();

My problem comes when I get the objects back from the database.

`em.getTransaction().begin();
Student s = em.find(Student.class, 2);
Cat c = em.find(Cat.class, 3);`

if( c != null )
   System.out.println(c.getYID() + ": " + c.getStudents());
if( s != null )
   System.out.println(s.getXID() + ": " + s.getCats());
em.getTransaction().commit();

The printout is:

3: {IndirectSet: not instantiated}

2: {IndirectSet: not instantiated}

This may very well be normal behavior. It just seems to me that when I get the objects back from the table, their Sets relating to the other objects should be populated. What I mean to say is, since the junction table looks like this:

X | Y

2  |  3

1  |  3

em.find(Cat.class,3) should return a Cat object with a set of {1,2} for getStudents() and em.find(Student.class,2) should return a Student object with a set of {3} for getCats().

Is there any way to make this possible?

Thanks,
B.J.

Comment: Are you rolling your entity objects by hand or generating them? There should be setters for you sub objects (like .setStudents() inside the Cat class).

Comment: The getters and setters are implied. I put them in, I just didn't want to take up the room. My code compiles and runs, it just doesn't do what I'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) to your Cat object, to cascade your read operations.

With cascading set up properly you can change your saving code to;

```
Entitymanager em = emf.createEntityManager();

em.getTransaction().begin(); 
Student s = new Student(); 
Student s2 = new Student();
Cat c = new Cat();
// this should be c.setStudents(s2)
c.getStudents().add(s2); 
em.persist(c); 
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Honestly don't fully understand why you are trying to assign two student sets into cats, you should join both sets into one and then add them to cats.

You also may want to look into explicitly setting your fetch type, @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) or FetchType.EAGER.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a better example would have been:

`em.getTransaction().begin(); 
Student s = new Student(); 
Student s2 = new Student(); 
Cat c = new Cat(); 
em.persist(s); 
em.persist(s2);
em.persist(c); 
c.getStudents().add(s); 
c.getStudents().add(s2); 
em.getTransaction().commit();`

and then trying to say

`Cat c2 = em.find(Cat.class,c.getYID());
Student s3 = em.find(Student.class,s.getXID());
System.out.println(c2.getYID() + ": " + c2.getStudents());
System.out.println(s3.getXID() + ": " + s3.getCats());`

The above prints:

1: {[[Movie: movieID=2], [Movie: movieID=3]]}

2: {[]}

This makes no sense to me, since the cat with id=1 has a movie in its set with id=2, but the movie with id=2 does not have a cat in its set with id=1. (Changing the cascade type didn't seem to affect the results.)

Thanks so much for replying.

B.J.

Comment: It just seems that, based on the way the entities are set up, doing  c = em.find(Cat.class,1) should give me a cat object with all the XID's from all the rows in the x_y table whose YID is 1. It should basically be like saying: c.setStudents(select XID from x_y where YID = 1;)

Comment: Benny, just as a heads up, in the future you probably want to edit your question to add clarification or additional information.

Comment: That is odd, my recommendation to you would be to try generating the classes from Netbeans (I'm sure eclipse can do this also) as opposed to hand rolling them. If that doesn't work, come back and post more information.